# multiple images storing in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-image

I am facing the issue with image files storage in the array for further classification model training.

Issue: I have a dataframe with links column(let's call it photos_link), i need to read the link , get the image(all sizes are the same), convert it to array, append to the list , then convert this list into np.array. as a result of this script i should have an array with shape:(%quantity of photos%, %height ofphoto%, %width of photo%, %3- which shows that it is RGB image%). But i get only this shape: (%quantity of photos%, ) please tell me , where I am wrong. Code below:

```
links = [link1,link2,link3,link4,link5,link6,link7,link8,link9,link10]
train_images = []
for each in links:
    img = io.imread(each)
    img = rescale(img, 0.25, anti_aliasing=False)
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    train_images.append(img)
X_test = np.array(train_images)
```

```
X_test.shape output: (10,)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, welcome. Secondly, have you tried to index the train_images to see what one of the elements contains? to see if there is anything there? also, try to see what is img at the various points. there are so many steps you can do before stackoverflow comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like X_test is and array of arrays.

`X_test[0].shape`
Will return a shape of (y,x,3) if you in fact have an array of arrays.